# Iam not able to send special characters when responding to ussd protocol

Tags: ussd

When I use ussd protocol iam not able use special characters,the keyboard was just showing(1-9 )numbers
( ,)comma and(.)full stop but I need to use other special characters. May I know how can I use those symbols.

Answer (score 0):

please note that some mobile device manufactures do not display special characters for USSD dialogs. I've seen this on some Huawei devices. You may consider trying with a different mobile device or you avoid the use of special characters.